# reading .env with nextjs

Tags: next.js, dotenv

I am trying to read `.env` in next.js inside the `next.config.js`

this is how it looks

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: require("find-config")(".env") })

console.log(process.env.API_URL)

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
}
```

and this prints the value from `.env` on the server console.

And now If i use this `baseUrl` in the component like this

```
import config from "../../next.config";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: config.baseURL });
```

then even code does not compile

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./next.config.js
```

what can be the issue?

Comment: is your `axiosInstance` being used by a `getServerSideProps` render, api route or client side render? The filesystem is not present on client side.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to access your `axios` instance in a client side component. The filesystem in not available client side. Take a look at [NextJS Public Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser). If you prefix a `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in an environment variable you can access it on a client side component like this.

```
.env file
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL = 'https://myapi...'
```

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL });
```

Comment: yes that i can access using NEXT_PUBLIC -> problem i am facing is with reading .env , my .env is at different location.. so the dotenv is not working actually

Comment: ever figure this out?